# Proteus - problem with voltage and current measurements

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, parallel, proteus

Okay, don't hate me too much or criticize me here. I'm just new to Proteus and I don't know which part I got it wrong but if you'll help me out, I'd really appreciative it!

In the first picture, it's supposed to have a total current of 10 A and then 6.25 A, 1.25 A and 2.5 A respectively but it keeps me giving this weird numbers. I know they're quiet close however my professor won't accept it.

[image: current]

Same problem here too, obviously it's supposed to give out 125 V but why is it giving 124 V?
[image]

Comment: Hello and Welcome. For starters, could you please organise the schematics? conventions call for positive voltage on top, ground on bottom.

Comment: I do not use Proteus at all but have used many other circuit simulators. First thing I notice is that you do not have a **ground symbol**. Why is that important? Because it tells the simulator: this is 0 Volt. In your setup it has to make an assumption so it could assume your circuit is at 1.23456 Million Volt then it will calculate the voltage across your resistors by subtracting two large numbers, that can introduce **inaccuracy errors** which you see. So add a ground and try again. Add a ground to **each** circuit on the page.

Comment: What are the characteristics of B3 and B4?

Comment: Also I see that you have several **independent** circuits in your sheet as well. That is OK as long as they're **not floating** but in your sheet they are floating since you do not have grounds.

Comment: I bet the voltage source has a small series resistance built-in, and its default value is 0.1Ω.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, so floating means a circuit that doesn't a ground?

Comment: @W5VO, is there anythin i could do with it ?

Comment: *so floating means a circuit that doesn't a ground?* Yes, that is what it means. There is no path an electron can follow to ground. Imagine that you inject electrons somewhere in the circuit, can they "escape" to ground or are they forever trapped in your circuit? If so (trapped) then the circuit is floating. even if a simulator has no problem with a floating circuit, it is still **good practice** to place a ground connection. It also means that you **thought about that** and that's what your professor wants to see (I guess).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, thank you for that!!Have you used proteus before? I'm reallyyyyy nooob here so what is component is "ground". I'm sorry for asking.

Comment: No, have never used it. But Google: "ground symbol proteus" and you can find how to get it. It is somewhere in the "terminals" section.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, found it. haha but here's the thing still giving out the same answers.

Comment: Have you tried W5VO's suggestion? Look in the properties of the battery if it has a **series resistance** and if it does set it to **Zero**.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, that seriously solved the problem. Thank you guys :))). That saved the whole class. God Bless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not familiar with Proteus, some simulation packages will include a series resistance with the ideal voltage source. This is *usually* not an issue and helps the simulator solve "hard" SPICE problems like shorting out ideal voltage sources.

Going by the numbers, you expect 12.5 A, which corresponds to a resistance of 12.5 Ω. The actual current is 9.92 A, which means that the ideal voltage source is actually feeding 12.6 Ω. Your second figure confirms this, as the voltage across each resistor is 124 V, which is a reasonable figure if there is a 0.1 Ω resistor in series (1.2499 V rounded to 1 V).